# filename starting with ' '

Tags: filenames, space

How to create a file on windows with filename starting with ' ' space?

For testing purpose I need a file with filename starting with space.
In database such files are stored and I am unable to retrieve the same due to space.

Comment: You can trim() the value which you get from the table. Then this issue would not be any more

Answer (score 1):

Open a command line and type: `notepad " test.txt"` then save the file